# Understanding an algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computational-complexity

[image]

I want to understand the above algorithm. My solution says that the algorithm should return $0$ if $n$ is a prime or 1. Otherwise it returns the smallest (positive) non-trivial divisor.

Lets consider an example: Let $n=5$

We assign $d=2$ and $q=5$ in the first steps. It holds that $5>2$ so we assign $q=\frac{5}{2}$

Now it holds that $\lceil 2.5 \rceil=3 \neq 2.5$ so we return 2

But $5$ is a prime, so it should be returned $0$. What is wrong?

Sorry, if this question is easy. Iam pretty new to algorithms.

Comment: No, you return $d$ when $$\left\lceil \frac{n}{d}\right\rceil = \frac{n}{d}.$$ For $n = 5$, the comparison yields $\neq$, so $d$ is set to $3$, and then the loop condition fails ($d = 3 > q = 2.5$), so it returns $0$.

Comment: Okay. I understand my mistake. But why we do that: $d\leftarrow d+1$ is there any reason for doing that?

Comment: Well, you want to check the next number whether it divides $n$. `d += 1;` or `++d;` may be more familiar.

Comment: How can I compute an estimation of the running time?

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm says to return $d$ if $\lceil q\rceil=q$. In your case, $\lceil q\rceil\ne q$, so we proceed to the "else" part of the statement instead of returning $d$.